# How to control UWP Flyout in ViewModel?

Tags: mvvm, uwp, viewmodel, template10, flyout

I want to open and close my flyout from viewmodel.

Im using UWP and Template10. I intent to use Template10 [OpenFlyoutAction](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Behaviors-and-Actions#openflyoutaction) and Template10 [CloseFlyoutAction](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Behaviors-and-Actions#closeflyoutaction).

I created a bool property that stores open or close state. Not sure how to call OpenFlyoutAction in here.

```
    bool _IsFlyoutOpen = default(bool);
    public bool IsFlyoutOpen
    {
        get { return _IsFlyoutOpen; }
        set
        {
            var ofa = new OpenFlyoutAction();
            if (_IsFlyoutOpen)
            {
                // what should i call here to open flyout
            }
            else
            {
                // what should i call here to close flyout
            }
            Set(ref _IsFlyoutOpen, value);
        }
    }
```

I created 2 Command to open and close flyout by changing the field.

```
    DelegateCommand _CloseFlyout;
    public DelegateCommand CloseFlyout
       => _CloseFlyout ?? (_CloseFlyout = new DelegateCommand(() =>
       {
           _IsFlyoutOpen = false;
       }, () => true));


    DelegateCommand _OpenFlyout;
    public DelegateCommand OpenFlyout
       => _OpenFlyout ?? (_OpenFlyout = new DelegateCommand(() =>
       {
           _IsFlyoutOpen = true;
       }, () => true));
```

In xaml, i use DataTriggerBehaviour to monitor IsFlyoutOpen property and act accordingly. Not sure if this is the right way.

```
        <Button Content="Open flyout" Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.OpenFlyout}">
            <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                <Flyout Placement="Full">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Awesome Flyout!" />
                        <Button Content="Close flyout" Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.CloseFlyout}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Flyout>
            </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsFlyoutOpen}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="True">
                    <Behaviors:OpenFlyoutAction />
                </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>

                <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsFlyoutOpen}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="False">
                    <Behaviors:CloseFlyoutAction />
                </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Button>
```

Full source code can be had here. [Template10 Flyout Viewmodel](https://github.com/syaifulnizamyahya/T10FlyoutViewModel)

Comment: When do you want to open the flyout? Can you tell me the user action?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
<Button Content="Open flyout">
  <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    <Flyout>
      <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Something Useful" />
                    <Button Content="Close">
                        <!-- Call CloseFlyoutAction -->
                    </Button>
      </StackPanel>
     </Flyout>
 </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
 <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
        <Behaviors:OpenFlyoutAction />
    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
 </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
 </Button>
```

#### Open Flyout Action

https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Behaviors-and-Actions#openflyoutaction

#### Close Flyout Action

https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Behaviors-and-Actions#closeflyoutaction

You can also throw in a `ConditionalAction` to indicate that a condition has to be met before you can call `CloseFlyoutAction`.  Its all there on the wiki, almost all of the actual code is contained in XAML.